# TessBaseAPI() error

Tags: ocr, tesseract, raspberry-pi3

i am doing a project on ocr using tesseract in python on a raspberry pi 3 device

installed tesseract via pip and sucessfully imported tesseract

```
import tesseract
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
```

i am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/ff.py", line 53, in <module>
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TessBaseAPI'
```

some one please give a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

The package you're looking for is [Tesserocr](https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/), that is a Tesseract Python wrapper. You have to [install tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#installation) in your system, then you can install Tesserocr with

```
pip install tesserocr
```

To use the package `tesserocr` write

```
import tesserocr

api = tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI()
```